# Remove whole Tr if Td does value does not match - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with data I wish to filter. The filter is based on two factors. A ddl which has the corresponding columns and text input. Is there any way I can hide the whole tr when the value of the td does not match the search criteria, as-is for now only the td is removed.

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var row = document.getElementById('row');

    var x = document.getElementById('DDL_SearchType');
    var type =  x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;    
    $('#print_Table tr td[class =' +type+']').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As for now only the td is removed.

That's because you are only targeting the iterated `td`, when you call:

```
$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
```

What you need to do is to target the `tr` by calling `$(this).parent()`, so your code would be:

```
$('#print_Table tr td[class =' +type+']').filter(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
});
```